# How to analyze survey data with irrelevant category

Tags: survey, likert

I have data from a survey about people's joy from life, and what gives them joy. The questionnaire consist of 20 questions, with a scale similar to likert scale, where 1 - irrelevant,  2 - doesn't give me joy at all, 3 - doesn't give me much joy, 4 - gives me a bit of joy and 5 - gives me a lot of joy (something like that, I am not being accurate). For example: question number 1 is about kids. A subject with no kids, will choose 1, since it is not relevant. Subjects with kids, will choose a number from 2 to 5. In addition, I have a continuous variable from 0 to 100, describing how happy a subject is. I am interested in two things: 1. To find if any of the 20 questions are related to the score from 0 to 100, which questions affect happiness. 2. The correlation between questions, and if there are sub-groups of questions. I wanted to ask you how should I analyze the data ? Which methods should I use, and how do I handle the "not relevant" answer ? (do I turn it into missing values?). Thank you !